# mysql query for sum of multiple column's values where column name is coming from selection list

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a report where I am showing salary elements like base salary,target  bonus,allowances etc in a selection box and displaying data of total employee cost as per city, country, grade etc.
In the back-end the salary elements is the header of the employee detail table.

so my query looks like this,where salary_type is coming from salary elements selection box from web page:

```
    SELECT d.city, 
       d.country, 
       d.business_level_3, 
       d.level, 
       d.function, 
       d.performance_rating, 
       d.gender, 
       d.grade, 
       Count(d.user_id)             AS hc, 
       rate * Sum(d."+salarytype+") AS Sum_of_employee_cost, 
       rate * Avg(d."+salarytype+") AS Employee_cost_avg, 
       rate * Max(d."+salarytype+") AS Employee_cost_max, 
       rate * Min(d."+salarytype+") AS Employee_cost_min, 
       Sum(d."+salarytype+")        AS cost_o 
FROM   employee_salary_details d 
       INNER JOIN manage_country c 
               ON c.NAME = d.country 
       INNER JOIN currency_rates r 
               ON r.from_currency = c.currency_id 
WHERE  r.to_currency = "+to_currency+" 
GROUP  BY city, 
          country, 
          business_level_3, 
          level, 
          function, 
          performance_rating, 
          gender, 
          grade
```

Now My client wants to enable multi-selection on salary elements and the report should come with the total of selected multiple salary elements like employee cost for base and target salary or employee cost of all salary types.

These salary elements are coming from another table and are dynamic.

What is the best way of achieving it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the result of this query is being used on a webpage, one option is to move the logic from the SQL side to the front-end side. Modify the SQL query to return all the columns you need, have your back-end serve up all the data to the front-end, and then the front-end (Javascript) can perform the sum/min/max-ing based on the chosen attributes on the page.

Alternatively, when constructing the SQL query to send, your back-end logic that's assembling the SQL query can have more logic behind it. For example, in PHP:

```php
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT d.city, 
       d.country, 
       d.business_level_3, 
       d.level, 
       d.function, 
       d.performance_rating, 
       d.gender, 
       d.grade, 
       Count(d.user_id)             AS hc,
SQL;

if ($userOnlyPickedOneThing) {
  $sql += "rate * SUM(d." . $selectedColumn . ") AS Sum_of_employee_cost, ";
} else if ($userPickedTwoThings) {
  $sql += "rate * (SUM(d." . $thingOne . ")+SUM(d." . $thingTwo . ") AS Sum_of_employee_cost, ";
}
```

You build up your SQL more piecemeal, depending on how the request was structured.